# How to render field from another associated table? Ruby on rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have 3 models: User, Order and UserOrder

**user_order.rb**

```
belongs_to :user, :class_name => "User"
belongs_to :order, :class_name => "Order"
```

**user.rb**

```
has_many :user_orders, foreign_key: :user_id,
                      dependent: :destroy
has_many :ordering, through: :user_orders,
                  source: :order
```

**order.rb**

```
has_many :reverse_user_orders, foreign_key: :order_id, 
                              dependent: :destroy,
                              class_name: "UserOrder"

has_many :orderers, through: :reverse_user_orders, source: :user
```

I have controller action in **orders_controller.rb**, which creates the relationship between user and order and it works fine (it creates the record in the database)

```
 def create
 ...
   if @order.save
    current_user.order!(@order)
 ....
```

I want to render user.name in the **orders' index.html.erb** file

```
<%= order.orderers.name %>
```

but in HTML it only renders caption "User". If I use <%= order.orderers %> it returns the full hash, including user.name.

```
[#<User id: 19, name: "Peter Jackson", email: "foobar@vk.com", remember_token:   "pj6eI2mc2_6G0UbumoEqMA", password_reset_token: nil, password_reset_sent_at: nil, created_at: "2013-01-27 14:10:15", updated_at: "2013-01-27 14:10:28", provider: nil, uid: nil, passport: nil, region: "Zimbabve"]
```

Any way to render user.name in orders' index.html.erb?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= order.orderers.first.name %> #for the first orderer.

<%= order.orderers.last.name %> #for the last orderer.
```

of for each orderer:

```
<% for o in order.orderers %>
  <%= o.name %>
 <% end %>
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks!! second part is very helpful

Answer (score 1):

`order.orderers` will return an Array instead of a single value. If you want to print `name` of first "orderer". Then do something like :

```
<%= order.orderers.first.name %>
```